# how to measure the stability of factor loadings?

Tags: factor-models, fama-french, opentaps-climate

Is there any research on how to measure the stability of factor loadings, for example from Fama French/Carhart type factor models?

The goal is to test different ways to construct a risk factor, such as for example a risk factor for climate/carbon risk.  One criterion is that the risk factor produces loadings which are relatively stable.